# Left join that will exclude certain rows

Tags: mysql, sql

When I left join the following tables, I get the results for all the id's. I need to exclude the results where there is no single id present in sms table.
So the expected output is as follows:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| messageid | mobilenos |
+-----------+-----------+
| a         |        12 |
| c         |        31 |
+-----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The messageid "d" should not be displayed in the output because there is not a single entry for "d" in the sms table.

I will like to know if the following query is correct or if there is a better way:

```
select a.* from splitvalues as a 
left join sms as b on a.messageid = b.batchid and a.mobilenos = b.destination 
left join (select a.messageid from splitvalues as a left join sms as b on a.messageid = b.batchid  where b.batchid is null) as dt on dt.messageid = a.messageid where dt.messageid is null and b.destination is null;
```

Following are the table details:

```
splitvalues
messageid mobilenos
a 10
a 11
a 12
b 20
b 21
b 22
b 23
b 24
c 30
c 31
d 40
d 41
d 42
d 43

sms
batchid destination
a 10
a 11
b 20
b 21
b 22
b 23
b 24
c 30

drop table if exists splitvalues;
drop table if exists sms;

create table if not exists splitvalues (messageid varchar(255), mobilenos int);
create table if not exists sms (batchid varchar(255), destination int);
insert into splitvalues values ('a', 10), ('a', 11), ('a', 12), ('b', 20), ('b', 21), ('b', 22), ('b', 23), ('b', 24), ('c', 30), ('c', 31), ('d', 40), ('d', 41), ('d', 42), ('d', 43);

insert into sms values ('a', 10), ('a', 11), ('b', 20), ('b', 21), ('b', 22), ('b', 23), ('b', 24), ('c', 30);

mysql> select a.* from splitvalues as a left join sms as b on a.messageid = b.batchid and a.mobilenos = b.destination where b.destination is null;
+-----------+-----------+
| messageid | mobilenos |
+-----------+-----------+
| a         |        12 |
| c         |        31 |
| d         |        40 |
| d         |        41 |
| d         |        42 |
| d         |        43 |
+-----------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you use inner join instead of left join?

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

### select a.* from [dbo].[splitvalues] a join [dbo].[sms] b on a.messageid=b.batchid

Or

### select a.* from [dbo].[splitvalues] a ,[dbo].[sms] b where a.messageid=b.batchid

Answer (score -2):

Try **inner join** it will produce rows which exists in both table,

```
select * from splitvalues as a
inner join sms as b on a.messageid = b.batchid and a.mobilenos = b.destination
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from
splitvalues
where mobilenos not in(select destination from sms) limit 2;
```